# GCP IAP Java example returning ComputeEngineCredentials instead of ServiceAccountCredentials

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iap

#### Context

I have some services in Google AppEngine Flexible environment communicating through APIs, and while I am using IAP for managing user access. I have to programmatically authenticate each service with the Bearer JWT token.

#### Problem

In my Java Application, I am using the code google is providing to authenticate IAP services, that you can find here: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-java

The problem is in this block of code:

```java
GoogleCredentials credentials =
    GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Collections.singleton(IAM_SCOPE));
// service account credentials are required to sign the jwt token
if (credentials == null || !(credentials instanceof ServiceAccountCredentials)) {
  throw new Exception("Google credentials : service accounts credentials expected");
}
return (ServiceAccountCredentials) credentials;
```

The `createScoped` method is returning a `ComputeEngineCredentials` while the code is expecting a `ServiceAccountCredentials` response object.

All the suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance for the greatest community ever.

Comment: This is occuring because I am running my Java service in flexible environment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/DefaultCredentialsProvider.java#L195 But then, how can we authenticate in the Java flexible environment ??

Comment: I think that the only way, is to use a json service account file...

Comment: I have come upon the same problem. I am able to get the correct ServiceAccountCredentials if I have the environment variable set that points to a local json credentials file for the service account I am trying to impersonate (even if it is the compute engine default service account). This happens on a compute engine instance. Were you able to get past the problem?

Comment: I was not trying to impersonate the authentication, I was just trying to authenticate without having to provide the JSON file

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually mention the nature of the difficulty you are faced with. 
The App Engine flexible environment service account is automatically created in a GCP project. Do you try to create the App Engine flexible environment service account is a separate service account from the [App Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/access-control#using_service_accounts). 
The "return (ServiceAccountCredentials) credentials;" statement uses a cast to return ServiceAccountCredentials; it should be fine.

Line: GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Collections.singleton(IAM_SCOPE) creates a GoogleCredentials object, it does not need a JSON service account file to succeed.

Comment: Have you seen my comment ? `DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:L195` There is a test for AppEngine standard only

Comment: Also the test for the `ServiceAccountCredentials` Object is made before the cast. So it will always throw the Exception `"Google credentials : service accounts credentials expected"`

Comment: Yes a default service account is automatically created but it's useless in the Java flexible environment. The line you noticed returns a ComputeEngineCredentials because the default service account can't be used (ie the environment variable is not set)

Comment: It is possible to set environment variables. For details, you may have a look at the "Defining environment variables" [sub-chapter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#defining_environment_variables) on "app.yaml Configuration File" page.

Comment: Yes I know but, if I set them manually I can't use the default service account (the file path is supposed to be automatically handled with gcp). Like for other languages I don't have to set any env var to use the default credentials.

Comment: To create keys for your service accounts, including the App Engine app default service account, use the Service Accounts page in the GCP Console to view and edit your service accounts. You may find related details on the "Access Control" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/access-control#using_your_service_account).